# Having trouble using a multiple criteria search bar/button in Site.Master from an SQL server (C# / ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Hey people I'm having a little issue regarding a transfer of variables from Site.Master to another window, the purpose is to make a search function accessed from the whole asp.net web application...

The code which is relevant from Site.Master:

```
<div class="search">
        <asp:Label ID="LandID" runat="server" Text="LandID"/>
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="CarBrand" runat="server" Text="CarBrand" />
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch2" runat="server" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Model" runat="server" Text="Model"/>
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch3" runat="server" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Style="width: 100px" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />
</div>
```

The Code from Site.Master.Cs:

```
public static string Text { get; set; }
public static string Text2 { get; set; }
public static string Text3 { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text = txtSearch.Text;
    Text2 = txtSearch2.Text;
    Text3 = txtSearch3.Text;
    Response.Redirect("search.aspx");
}
```

The code from the search.aspx:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LandID" HeaderText="LandID" SortExpression="LandID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Bilmaerk" HeaderText="Bilmaerk" SortExpression="Bilmaerk" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Variant" HeaderText="Variant" SortExpression="Variant" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartYear" HeaderText="StartYear" SortExpression="StartYear" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SlutYear" HeaderText="SlutYear" SortExpression="SlutYear" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Volumen" HeaderText="Volumen" SortExpression="Volumen" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MaxDrej" HeaderText="MaxDrej" SortExpression="MaxDrej" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AntalCylindre" HeaderText="AntalCylindre" SortExpression="AntalCylindre" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TopHast" HeaderText="TopHast" SortExpression="TopHast" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Acceleration" HeaderText="Acceleration" SortExpression="Acceleration" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Beskrivelse" HeaderText="Beskrivelse" SortExpression="Beskrivelse" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Effekt" HeaderText="Effekt" SortExpression="Effekt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Picture" HeaderText="Picture" SortExpression="Picture" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<selectparameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="<%=Text1 %>"></asp:ControlParameter>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="<%=Text2 %>"></asp:ControlParameter>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="<%=Text3 %>"></asp:ControlParameter>
</selectparameters>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Bil] WHERE (([LandID] LIKE '%' +@LandID+ '%') AND ([Bilmaerk] LIKE '%' +@Bilmaerk+ '%') AND ([Model] LIKE '%' +@Model+ '%'))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Text1" Name="LandID" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"
            DefaultValue="%" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Text2" Name="Bilmaerk" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"
            DefaultValue="%" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Text3" Name="Model" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"
            DefaultValue="%" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

the Relevant code from search.aspx.cs:

```
   public partial class search : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
protected string Text1 { get; set; }
protected string Text2 { get; set; }
protected string Text3 { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text1 = SiteMaster.Text;
    Text2 = SiteMaster.Text2;
    Text3 = SiteMaster.Text3;
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Constructor.SelectedCar = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    Response.Redirect("Selected.aspx");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page load  or page prerender of the master based on the life cycle of your page, initially store the values the textboxes of different search fields into the session variables respectively.

And then you can access these variables on search button click then you can proceed further of the basic steps like going to database and search the relevant fields and so on.

By using these session variables you can access them anywhere in any page untill and unless you change the values....

```
   public void search(object sender ,EventArgs e)
    {
        string Search = session["search"].toString();
        Search =  Search + "%";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("search", Search);
            Search = "%" + Search;//for user name ,user email,languages made the search criteria as anywhere in the word for others it is starting letter
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();//again we have to clear and add since search is changed
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("search", Search);
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [UserID], [UserName], [UserEmail], [UserContact], [UserAddress], [Gender], [Languages], [Status], [Passwords],[Image] FROM [Users_raghu] where [UserName] like @search";
    }
```

This is the sample you can refer here I have given you only one search variable in your case you have to take 3 session variables and proceed further

Hope this helps :D

Comment: yeah but what the real question was is how do I get the variables from the "behind-code" now I made it the easy transfer... how do I access them from a pure .aspx file so that it can make the GridView correctly

Comment: I didn't get the question you are asking. The thing now is that you are able to transfer the variables from 1 page to other using sessions.Then the work is done no, the thing you have to do is send those variables as parameters to the database and make the grid view according to the result you got from the output

Comment: I have changed the answer you can see how to code behind using the session variables if you have any doubts you can ask

Comment: it was utmost useful kind sir... just removed all the unnecessary code that I had written before that...

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use session to transfer data from one page to another..??
its quite simple ,

```
//this is how you will create the Session on master page 
{
   Session["text"] = txtearch.Text;
   Session["Text2"] = txtSearch2.Text;
   Session["Text3"] = txtSearch3.Text;
}

on another page just use it like
{
   string a = Session["text"].ToString();
   string b = Session["text2"].ToString();
   string c = Session["text3"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: hmm I think I haven't learned of it yet... or just simply have had it gone past me...

Answer (score 0):

Try use HTTP GET method like code bellow:

### On your Site.Master.Cs

```
protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text = txtSearch.Text;
    Text2 = txtSearch2.Text;
    Text3 = txtSearch3.Text;
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("search.aspx?txtSearch={0}&txtSearch2={1}&txtSearch3={2}", Text, Text2, Tex3));
}
```

### On your search.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text1 = Request["txtSearch"];
    Text2 = Request["txtSearch2"];
    Text3 = Request["txtSearch3"];
}
```

Also you can add GET parameter to your master page control by call:

```
(Master.FindControl("txtSearch") as TextBox).Text = Request["txtSearch"];
```